# Laravel Eloquent update not updating one field

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I am using Laravel API along with VueJS Frontend application. I send `axios` `POST` call along with some information which the user puts about himself. In the backend, I take that data and update the user record in the MySQL database.

This is my backend code:

```
$user = User::where(['logintoken' => $request->login_token, 'remember_token' => $request->remember_token])->first();
            if (!$user) {
                $status = 404;
                $response = ['status' => false, 'message' => 'User not found.'];
            } else {
                $affectedRows = $user->update([
                    'country' => $request->input('country'),
                    'city' => $request->input('city'),
                    'state' => $request->input('state'),
                    'dob' => $request->input('dob'),
                    'language' => $request->input('language'),
                    'street' => $request->input('street'),
                    'house' => $request->input('house'),
                    'avatar' => $request->input('avatar'),
                    'birthplace' => $request->input('birthplace'),
                    'type' => $request->input('userType'),
                    'bio' => $request->input('bio'),
                    'zip' => $request->input('zip'),
                    'has-completed-profile' => 1
                ]);
                if (!$affectedRows) {
                    $response = ['status' => false, 'message' => 'Error updating'];
                    $status = 500;
                } else {
                    $response = ['status' => true, 'message' => 'User updated successfully', 'updated_record' => $user, 'request' => $affectedRows, 'zip' => $request->input('zip')];
                }
            }
```

Now, this code is working perfectly fine, except, it is not updating the `zip` field. I `console.log()` the response in VueJS side, and I see that the `zip` value is correct and also the data type fo `zip` field in the DB is string.

Still, this is not working for the `zip` column. When I had created the `users` migration, there was no `zip` column, but after some time, when I needed it, I created another migration and used it to alter the table to insert the `zip` field.

Any idea on why it isn't working?

Comment: You need to add that column in Model class of it

Comment: Are you using empty `$guarded` array in your `User` model? Or if you use `$fillable` you will need to add the `zip` in the array of allowed fields.

Comment: Try `Log::info($request->all());` and check the log in `/storage/logs` to verify that the zip is being passed into the request.

Comment: @RahulMeshram yes, I am a dumbass to forget that! You should add it as an Answer, LOL.

Comment: Can you share .blade view code and also as @nakvov mentioned, verify if zip is listed in $fillable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add that field in Respective Model class.

This should solve your problem.

`$fillable` serves as a "white list" of attributes that should be mass assignable. So, to get started, you should define which model attributes you want to make mass assignable. You may do this using the `$fillable` property on the model. For example, let's make the  `zip` attribute of our `User` model mass assignable:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['zip', // your rest column names];
}
```

This example should help you sort your problem.

Here is the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models).

Comment: how do I add the values in the controller then ?

Comment: If you have model for Entity, then Why you want it in Controller.?

Answer (score 3):

You probably missed `zip` in you model's `$fillable`.

So add it, it should look like this:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'country', 'city', 'state', 'dob', 'language', 'street', 'house', 'avatar', 'birthplace', 'type', 'bio', 'zip', 'has-completed-profile'
    ];
```

[Find documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment)